# Intellij Idea, how to deploy war on already running Glassfish

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy on Glassfish with another configuration that the one that start Glassfish initially.

But, I got an error that the port 4848 is already used. Obviously, it's the port of the Glassfish admin.

How can I deploy with another configuration to that already started server without getting that error? (like in Netbeans)

Thanks in advance

Julien

Answer (score 0):

Select project --> Click on Run in menu --> Edit configurations

Comment: It's not what I'm wanting to do. I've already many configurations. but when I run the first one, sometimes I just want to deploy another part of the application only. But with the actual configuration, I can't do  that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two configurations to do this. The first would deploy your entire app and the second would deploy a part of it. In the second configuration, along with the deployment details you will want to specify the "On 'Update' action" appropriately.

In your configuration you can specify what you want deployed for that configuration. In "Glassfish Server Run/Debug Configuration" click on the Deployment tab and you can choose the specific artifacts in there.

Then once you have the part of the application you want to deploy specified in that tab, you can tell IDEA whether or not it should simply redeploy, or restart the server, or simply update classes and resources, or simply update resources when you run the configuration. This setting can be found in the "Server" tab in the "On 'Update' action" combo box.